# Which riders in the 2015 Tour de France have proven doping history?

Tags: history, cycling, tour-de-france, doping

How many, and who, of the 198 riders to start the Tour de France in 2015 have a *proven* history of doping? I.e. they have been charged and found guilty by WADA/UCI at some point in the past, or have confessed, or been proven to have doped (but time has expired in which charges can be brought etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of the starters (On the right side of [this page](http://www.steephill.tv/tour-de-france/)). The following have proven history of doping:

1. [Alberto Contador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Contador#Doping)
2. [Ryder Hesjedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryder_Hesjedal)
3. [Ivan Basso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Basso)
4. [Alejandro Valverde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alejandro_Valverde)
5. [Michele Scarponi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michele_Scarponi)
6. [Filippo Pozzato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filippo_Pozzato)
7. [Rui Costa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rui_Costa_(cyclist))
8. [Damiano Caruso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damiano_Caruso)
9. [Daniele Bennati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniele_Bennati)
10. [Giampaolo Caruso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giampaolo_Caruso)

---

The Dutch public broadcasting station NOS stated on [their website (in Dutch)](http://nos.nl/tour/artikel/2044912-negen-dopingzondaars-in-de-tour.html) a list of nine riders who used doping in their past. In their list they do not mention Ryder Hesjedal who confessed to have used doping, as he has never faced charges nor did he get a ban.

<del>[Daryl Impey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daryl_Impey)</del> (cleared of the doping charges)